# How automatically start an outbound SSH connection on a server when an internal client connects to that server

Tags: ssh

**Question**

**How to automatically start an outbound SSH connection on a server when an internal client connects to that server on a specific port, for any given service? (not just sshd on the server, and only if the outbound ssh connection has not already been started).**

---

**Summary of intended solution**

Client sends a packet to server ---> server sees it is from a given ip range --> server checks if outbound ssh connection is already running --> server finds it is not running and brings up connection --> client packets flow through to far remote end via outbound ssh connection

---

**Other considerations**

sshd's `ForceCommand` would work almost perfectly for this except that the question is asking for a solution to start an outbound ssh connection, if it does not already exist, when a client connects to *any* service on the server. (Almost perfect because even if the `ForceCommand` solution could start a connection, for this particular question, it does not have a way to check for an already existing connection, and not run the command if a connection already exists. Also, as noted, the question is asking for an outbound ssh connection to start when a client connects to *any* service, not just sshd).

---

**Research**

Research on the topic suggests a script will be needed to log never before seen connections through iptables using `-m state ! --state seen_reply`, then check the log in the background, and if a match is found, check if the outbound ssh connection is not already up, and if not, start it.

My research so far found a sample script that needs work

```
#######auto_ssh-script.sh

####### iptables rule logging all new incoming, unestablished, never before seen connections

iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state NEW -m state !
--state ESTABLISHED -m state ! --state SEEN_REPLY -j LOG --log-prefix CONNECT

#######background script  --> read log and look for a match to string CONNECT 

cat /proc/kmsg | while read LOGGING 
do   
    LOG='echo "$LOGGING" | grep 'CONNECT' '   
    if ["$LOG" = ' ' ]  &  UP= 'echo alxw | grep ssh '
     if [ "UP" = ' '] then 
     fi  

ssh -p 22 <user>@<somewhere-out-there>.com
echo "Connected"
done
```

Update - `netcat` might help as well.

From stackoverflow.com

```
#!/bin/bash

netcat -lk -p 12345 | while read line
do
    match=$(echo $line | grep -c 'Keep-Alive')
    if [ $match -eq 1 ]; then
        echo "Here run whatever you want..."
    fi
done
```

Also found another useful snippet from stackoverflow.com as well -

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh-auth() {
# Start the SSH agent only if not running
[[ -z $(ps | grep ssh-agent) ]] && echo $(ssh-agent) > /tmp/ssh-agent-data.sh

# Identify the running SSH agent
[[ -z $SSH_AGENT_PID ]] && source /tmp/ssh-agent-data.sh > /dev/null

# Authenticate (change key path or make a symlink if needed)
[[ -z $(ssh-add -l | grep "/home/$(whoami)/.ssh/id_rsa")]] && ssh-add }
```

Even more from stackoverflow.com

```
#!/bin/bash

REMOTEUSER=username
REMOTEHOST=remotehost 

SSH_REMOTEPORT=22
SSH_LOCALPORT=10022

TUNNEL_REMOTEPORT=8080
TUNNEL_LOCALPORT=8080

createTunnel() {
    /usr/bin/ssh -f -N  -L$SSH_LOCALPORT:$REMOTEHOST:SSH_REMOTEPORT -L$TUNNEL_LOCALPORT:$REMOTEHOST:TUNNEL_REMOTEPORT $REMOTEUSER@$REMOTEHOST
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo Tunnel to $REMOTEHOST created successfully
    else
        echo An error occurred creating a tunnel to $REMOTEHOST RC was $?
    fi
}

## Run the 'ls' command remotely.  If it returns non-zero, then create a new connection
/usr/bin/ssh -p $SSH_LOCALPORT $REMOTEUSER@localhost ls >/dev/null 2>&1
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo Creating new tunnel connection
    createTunnel
fi
```

---

**Additional Research**

There is also this from superuser.com -

https://superuser.com/questions/718978/automatic-ssh-tunnel

Comment: It is a unique way to go about solving nearly this same problem. Uncertain of the solution's validity.